How do I enable Google Authenticator (TOTP) with SSH keys with a passphrase on Debian 12?
TL;DR: I ran google-authenticator when logged in as the root user. I should've run it as my normal user account instead.
I have just installed Debian 12 on a spare Apple Mac Mini. I want to control it via SSH from my iMac. I want to use SSH keys with a passphrase and I also wish to use Google Authenticator for multi-factor authentication.
On the iMac, I created ssh keys using ssh-keygen -t rsa and specified a passphrase. I then used ssh-copy-id david@192.168.4.7 to copy the public key onto the remote Debian server.
I then wanted to disable password-only login, so I added the following two lines at the end of /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
Match User david
PasswordAuthentication no

I then ran systemctl restart sshd and logged out of the remote machine. I then tried to log back in, and I was asked for the passphrase, but not the password. So far, so good.
I then followed these two guides for setting up Google Authenticator:
Guide 1
Guide 2
(I logged in as the root user so I didn't need to add sudo at the start of everything...)
Specifically:
apt install -y libpam-google-authenticator
google-authenticator
(answered yes to all four questions asked by Google Authenticator setup)
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
->Set UsePAM yes
->Added a line at the end of the file "ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes"
->Added another line at the end of the file "AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive"
->Saved and closed /etc/ssh/sshd_config
nano /etc/pam.d/sshd
->Commented out the line "@include common-auth"
->Added a line at the end of the file "auth   required   pam_google_authenticator.so"
->Saved and closed /etc/pam.d/sshd
systemctl restart ssh

I then tried to log in with a different terminal window on my iMac, but I get the following error:

Received disconnect from 192.168.4.7 port 22:2: no authentication methods enabled
Disconnected from 192.168.4.7 port 22

I was able to revert my changes to the two files and re-connect just using the passphrase. However, I'm unable to get it to ask me for my passphrase and the Google Authenticator code.
What am I doing wrong please?
I found a similar issue, but the only answer on it doesn't provide enough detail.

Then make sure that PAM authentication is required by your configuration (PAM password authentication part is skipped if publickey authentication method succeeds). You can do that by setting appropriate AuthenticationMethods in sshd_config.

Unfortunately, they don't explain how to set "appropriate AuthenticationMethods in sshd_config", so that isn't of much help to me...
Thank you in advance.
Complete contents of /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
Match User david
PasswordAuthentication no
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive

(plus a bunch of other lines that I have omitted because they are commented-out).
Complete contents of /etc/pam.d/sshd:
account    required     pam_nologin.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
@include common-session
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]
session    required     pam_limits.so
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
@include common-password
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so

(plus a bunch of other lines that I have omitted because they are commented-out)
Update after being advised to check the logs by Zoredache in the comments...
Complete output of ssh -vvv david@192.168.4.7 run on the iMac when trying to connect to the Mac Mini:
$ ssh -vvv david@192.168.4.7
OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[omitting a very long log file with no useful information as this website has a character limit and I would exceed it if I kept this here]
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension publickey-hostbound@openssh.com
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 1
Received disconnect from 192.168.4.7 port 22:2: no authentication methods enabled
Disconnected from 192.168.4.7 port 22

...nothing terribly helpful there.
Checking the logs on the Mac Mini:
$ journalctl --since "1 hour ago" 
Jul 09 06:50:05 docker1 sshd[10682]: error: Disabled method "keyboard-interactive" in AuthenticationMethods list "publickey,keyboard-interactive"
Jul 09 06:50:05 docker1 sshd[10682]: Authentication methods list "publickey,keyboard-interactive" contains disabled method, skipping
Jul 09 06:50:05 docker1 sshd[10682]: error: No AuthenticationMethods left after eliminating disabled methods
Jul 09 06:50:05 docker1 sshd[10682]: error: Disabled method "keyboard-interactive" in AuthenticationMethods list "publickey,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
Jul 09 06:50:05 docker1 sshd[10682]: Authentication methods list "publickey,keyboard-interactive" contains disabled method, skipping [preauth]
Jul 09 06:50:05 docker1 sshd[10682]: error: No AuthenticationMethods left after eliminating disabled methods [preauth]
Jul 09 06:50:05 docker1 sshd[10682]: Disconnecting authenticating user david 192.168.4.6 port 50344: no authentication methods enabled [preauth]
Jul 09 06:53:00 docker1 sshd[10702]: error: Disabled method "keyboard-interactive" in AuthenticationMethods list "publickey,keyboard-interactive"
Jul 09 06:53:00 docker1 sshd[10702]: Authentication methods list "publickey,keyboard-interactive" contains disabled method, skipping
Jul 09 06:53:00 docker1 sshd[10702]: error: No AuthenticationMethods left after eliminating disabled methods
Jul 09 06:53:00 docker1 sshd[10702]: error: Disabled method "keyboard-interactive" in AuthenticationMethods list "publickey,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
Jul 09 06:53:00 docker1 sshd[10702]: Authentication methods list "publickey,keyboard-interactive" contains disabled method, skipping [preauth]
Jul 09 06:53:00 docker1 sshd[10702]: error: No AuthenticationMethods left after eliminating disabled methods [preauth]
Jul 09 06:53:00 docker1 sshd[10702]: Disconnecting authenticating user david 192.168.4.6 port 50587: no authentication methods enabled [preauth]

Ah-hah!
Did some Googling, found this, and specifically noted the quote regarding "KbdInteractiveAuthentication".
I then went into /etc/ssh/sshd_config and changed  KbdInteractiveAuthentication from no to yes. I also commented-out the line ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes as this seems to be deprecated.
systemctl restart sshd

I then attempted to log in again. I got closer; I was asked for the passphrase and for the Google Authenticator code. However, the Google Authenticator code was repeatedly rejected, and I was unable to log in.
$ ssh -vvv david@192.168.4.7
OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/david/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/david/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for 192.168.4.7
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.4.7 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.4.7 [192.168.4.7] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/david/.ssh/docker1_id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/david/.ssh/docker1_id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.4.7:22 as 'david'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts:32
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts:33
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from 192.168.4.7
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug3: kex_choose_conf: will use strict KEX ordering
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:YqWOIqPh7NqasxGY07Yef+WDD52F/48qBkbiWlQxIE8
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts:32
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts:33
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from 192.168.4.7
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '192.168.4.7' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/david/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension server-sig-algs
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension publickey-hostbound@openssh.com
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.7ZPATgtfUu/Listeners'
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/david/.ssh/docker1_id_rsa RSA SHA256:Pk6ndbhbaLetYzTmHflWGqvG8gaO7CIyUp/XcpRT4S0 explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/david/.ssh/docker1_id_rsa RSA SHA256:Pk6ndbhbaLetYzTmHflWGqvG8gaO7CIyUp/XcpRT4S0 explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/david/.ssh/docker1_id_rsa RSA SHA256:Pk6ndbhbaLetYzTmHflWGqvG8gaO7CIyUp/XcpRT4S0 explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey-hostbound-v00@openssh.com with RSA SHA256:Pk6ndbhbaLetYzTmHflWGqvG8gaO7CIyUp/XcpRT4S0
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:Pk6ndbhbaLetYzTmHflWGqvG8gaO7CIyUp/XcpRT4S0
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/david/.ssh/docker1_id_rsa': 
debug2: bad passphrase given, try again...
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/david/.ssh/docker1_id_rsa': 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
Authenticated using "publickey" with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: entering
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
(david@192.168.4.7) Verification code: 
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: entering
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
(david@192.168.4.7) Verification code: 
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: entering
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
(david@192.168.4.7) Verification code: 
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
david@192.168.4.7: Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).

On the Mac Mini:
journalctl --since "2 minutes ago"
Jul 09 07:20:18 docker1 sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[10989]: Failed to read "/home/david/.google_authenticator" for "david"
Jul 09 07:20:18 docker1 sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[10989]: No secret configured for user david, asking for code anyway.
Jul 09 07:20:25 docker1 sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[10989]: Invalid verification code for david
Jul 09 07:20:25 docker1 sshd[10987]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for david from 192.168.4.6
Jul 09 07:20:25 docker1 sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[10993]: Failed to read "/home/david/.google_authenticator" for "david"
Jul 09 07:20:25 docker1 sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[10993]: No secret configured for user david, asking for code anyway.
Jul 09 07:20:33 docker1 sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[10993]: Invalid verification code for david
Jul 09 07:20:33 docker1 sshd[10987]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for david from 192.168.4.6
Jul 09 07:20:33 docker1 sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[10996]: Failed to read "/home/david/.google_authenticator" for "david"
Jul 09 07:20:33 docker1 sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[10996]: No secret configured for user david, asking for code anyway.
Jul 09 07:20:42 docker1 sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[10996]: Invalid verification code for david
Jul 09 07:20:42 docker1 sshd[10987]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for david from 192.168.4.6
Jul 09 07:20:42 docker1 sshd[10987]: Connection closed by authenticating user david 192.168.4.6 port 52983 [preauth]

I then ran ls -asl inside /home/david/ and realised /home/david/.google_authenticator doesn't even exist.
Some more Googling, eventually I found this and realised that I ran the Google Authenticator configuration/setup when logged in as the root user, not the david user. Checking /root/, I found the  .google_authenticator file in there. I hadn't realised that the Google Authenticator configuration was supposed to be run as the user that needs that authentication method. In hindsight, if I had actually used my eyes, this should've been obvious, because the description for the code in the Google Authenticator app shows root@hostname, not david@hostname.
su david
google-authenticate
(Answer yes to everything and create a new code)

I then tried to log in once more, and this time, I was asked for the passphrase and the Google Authenticator code, and I was able to log in successfully.

Does anything get logged about this?  Have you checked your syslog or journal?  Have you tried increasing the verbosity of the sshd so it might log some more useful results?

Thank you Zoredache. You prompted me to figure out the problem. I ran google-authenticator when logged in as the root user when first setting that up. This created the .google_authenticator inside /root/ instead of /home/david/. I should've run it as my normal user account instead. Problem solved!

I ran google-authenticator when logged in as the root user. I should've run it as my normal user account instead.

(I will mark this as the accepted answer in 24 hours when I am allowed to do so)
